# Gravity fed containers

Tags: gravity

Curiosity got the better of me, and was wondering if you have two containers full of sand each at different heights but both fed in a tube from a with the containers being in Y configuration, is there any difference in which one drains first?

[image: Sand]

Comment: Can you draw a diagram to show what you're asking about?

Comment: Added, maybe that will help explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring that the effect is very small if the height difference between both containers is small, strictly speaking the one that is lower will experience a stronger gravitational pull, and as such, the sand should accelerate faster. This can be understood in terms of Newton's inverse square law for gravity, which basically states that the force experienced within a gravitational field grows as the distance is reduced. Since the lower container is closer to earth, its content will experience a greater force. As a consequence, it will drain faster.

Comment: As there is a greater "head" of sand in the pipe below the higher container, wouldn't that tend to increase the pressure at the point where its pipe meets the Y joint, potentially reversing the flow in the other pipe?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Assuming a sufficiently narrow pipe, such effects might occur. However, I do not think that the question was intended to include such effects.

Comment: Ah the question cropped up because some one told me that the higher one would drain quicker because of "Flow Theory" which the higher one would experience more velocity. Which didn't sound correct and after looking around a while I didn't see anything that possibly could suggest that. So I did wonder if smaller pipes could create pressure where that occurred. Thanks for all the insight